# After installing docker I am unable to run commands that I used to be able to run

Tags: linux, docker

Two examples include snap and certbot. I used to type sudo certbot and would be able to add ssl certs to my nginx servers. Now I get this every time I enter certbot. The same thing goes for snap. I'm new to docker and don't understand what is going on. Can somebody explain what is ging on?

```
Usage:  docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND

Docker Compose

Options:
      --ansi string                Control when to print ANSI control characters ("never"|"always"|"auto") (default "auto")
      --compatibility              Run compose in backward compatibility mode
      --env-file string            Specify an alternate environment file.
  -f, --file stringArray           Compose configuration files
      --profile stringArray        Specify a profile to enable
      --project-directory string   Specify an alternate working directory
                                   (default: the path of the, first specified, Compose file)
  -p, --project-name string        Project name

Commands:
  build       Build or rebuild services
  convert     Converts the compose file to platform's canonical format
  cp          Copy files/folders between a service container and the local filesystem
  create      Creates containers for a service.
  down        Stop and remove containers, networks
  events      Receive real time events from containers.
  exec        Execute a command in a running container.
  images      List images used by the created containers
  kill        Force stop service containers.
  logs        View output from containers
  ls          List running compose projects
  pause       Pause services
  port        Print the public port for a port binding.
  ps          List containers
  pull        Pull service images
  push        Push service images
  restart     Restart service containers
  rm          Removes stopped service containers
  run         Run a one-off command on a service.
  start       Start services
  stop        Stop services
  top         Display the running processes
  unpause     Unpause services
  up          Create and start containers
  version     Show the Docker Compose version information

Run 'docker compose COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

Comment: Does docker compose replace snap?

Comment: It seems like snap is linked to docker compose

Answer (score 0):

## NEVER INSTALL DOCKER WITH SNAP

I solved the problems. Not sure where everything went wrong, but I completely destroyed snapd from my system following this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280707/how-to-uninstall-snap. Then I installed snap again and everything works.

## INSTALL DOCKER WITH THE OFFICIAL GUIDE (APT)

Go here to install docker the correct way. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

If you are new to docker follow this advice and **NEVER TYPE** `snap install docker` into you terminal. Follow these words of wisdom or use the first half if you already messed up.